# Check if still mounted correctly

Tags: mount, webdav, davfs2

For my daemon, I mounted (several) remote read-only WebDAV folders¹ as "sources" to periodically pull files from. Let `$SOURCE` be one of them for this question's sake.

Before blindly using `$SOURCE`, I feel it'd be a good idea to check if the mount is still operational, as WebDAV is not known for superior stability, so checking at mount-time¹ is already done, it might also "break" later².

The following ideas don't seem to fit me:

- Testing for presence of a known remote file: `$SOURCE` is not necessarily controlled by me
- Testing for presence of anything at all: `$SOURCE` might as well be empty, so there'd be false negatives
- Checking output of `mount | grep " $SOURCE "`: Can't this produce false positives on netdevs?
- Checking result of `mountpoint -q "$SOURCE"`: Same about false positives?

More:

*The check should avoid using inappropriate amounts of network bandwidth and memory.* So additionally `curl`ing the DAV mounted at `$SOURCE` and checking for differences in the entire file/folder structure should obviously solve my problem, but also blows up that requirement in any possible way.

*The check should work in either bash³+"basic linux stuff" or microperl.* Bloating is bad for routers.

*I know `davfs2` uses a cache.* What if it's mounted, the structure is cached and then the connect fails? Wouldn't I end up with tons of empty files in `$SOURCE`?

---

¹ I invoke `davfs2` from a script. Heard you want me to be precise.

² Actually, my daemon should primarily be deployed in dynamic-IP environments at 24/7 use, so the sources *will* experience daily internet reconnects.

³ busybox's ash, to be precise again.

Comment: why not unmount/mount periodically?

Comment: @artm Seems a bit naïve to me. Would apparently clear the cache each time, thus also mitigating its benefits. Plus: Remounts of DAV are quite time consuming, so I'd be glad to keep them to a minimum.

Comment: What about "df"? Could you copy a small/random file and then read it back (or would local caching kill that?)

Comment: I did some research - apparently `ls`ing a broken source yields false positives, while `cat`ing a random file successfully identifies a failing source. Also, `cat`ing is sensibly inexpensive, as there are only "small" files expected in my scenario. My question now boils down to "How can I `cat` a random file in a folder?". Going to dig into that.

Comment: `cat $(find "$SOURCE" -type f | head -1)` works just about fine.

Comment: https://github.com/barrycarter/bcapps/blob/master/NAGIOS/bc-nagios-test.pl#L220 is probably overkill for your purposes, but does work.